# How to horizontally center text in bootstrap button?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I'm working on a simple pager (in Angular 2) but I have problems with the styling. I am using bootstrap for my page design and I use bootstrap buttons for the pager. I am using `line-height` for the vertical centering of the text and that works fine but I can't figure out how to horizontally center the text in the buttons. The text always appears at the right. I tried `text-align: center`, I tried the bootstrap class `text-center` but the text remains on the right.

My html is very simple:

```
<div class="pager">
    <button class="btn btn-sm" *ngFor="let page of pages">{{page}}</button>
</div>
```

(For those who don't know Angular 2: this iterates over the pages array and creates as many buttons as the array has values and uses the values as button texts)

My css (sass):

```
.pager {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 8px;

    button {
        max-height: 18px;
        max-width: 18px;
        margin-left: 2px;
        background: $topBarControlBackground;
        color: $topBarColor;
        line-height: 50%;
        font-size: 80%;
    }
}
```

And here is the result:
[image: pager]

```css
.pager {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 8px;

    button {
        max-height: 18px;
        max-width: 18px;
        margin-left: 2px;
        background: $topBarControlBackground;
        color: $topBarColor;
        line-height: 50%;
        font-size: 80%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="pager">
    <button class="btn btn-sm" *ngFor="let page of pages">{{page}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: update your js code

Comment: There is none that would work here as it is Angular 2. Pls remove the "Run code snippet" button. It doesn't make sense in this case. js is not involved in the styling of the buttons at all.

Comment: have you tried text-align: center !important ?

Comment: I hadn't but I just did and it made no difference.

Comment: try to replace the margin-left with padding, also I would create a plnkr instead of code snippet

Comment: in my codepen, padding on `btn-sm` and `btn` is messing up your text align. try setting custom padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

padding on `btn` and `btn-sm` is messing up the text-align. your buttons are too small to accommodate the padding. setting `padding:0 5px;` works for me. see the codepen [here](http://codepen.io/samia92/pen/AXREaX).

alternatively (without overriding padding), you can use the class `btn-xs` for extra-small buttons.

Comment: Thanks. You were very close. Setting padding left and right to 0 and using btn-xs fixed it.